# JavaScript validation not workig on HTML form

Tags: javascript

I want to validate my jsp form.

My test.jsp page is given below

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress");
        alert("Address : " + address);
        if (address == null || address == "") {
            alert("Enter Address");
            return false;
        }

        var city = document.getElementById("txtCity");
        if (city == null || city == "") {
            alert("Enter City");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="TestForm1" action="loginServlet" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Address :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtAddress" value="${reqObj.address}" /></td>
                <td>City :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtCity" value="${reqObj.city}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="left">
                <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <%
            String createdDate = "";
            Date dt = new Date();
            createdDate = dt.toString();
            System.out.println("currentTime>>>>" + createdDate);
        %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Problem is that,
When run this Project my test.jsp form is displayed with empty Address field and when i click on Submit Button alert is showing "Address : null"

But when i write some value on Address textbox field then i click on Submit Button again it showing me "Address : null"

I am using JAVA with Eclipse Mars 1.

Comment: you are trying to fetch the value by id but you haven't defined Id anywhere in the input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `id` attribute is present in the jsp.

```
<input type="text" name="txtAddress" value="${reqObj.address}" />
```

Add `id`(`id="txtAddress"`) attr and then use `document.getElementById("txtAddress");`

```
<input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" value="${reqObj.address}" />
```

And you can check for `length` instead of `null` and `""`

```
if(address.value.trim().length == 0)
```

Not only using `id` one can get using `class,name,tag` also

- `document.getElementById("xyz");`
- `document.getElementsByTagName("p");`
- `document.getElementsByClassName("abc");`
- `document.getElementsByName("xyz");`

**Update:** Mainly you are missing taking **`value`** of that element.Take the value and then check

**`address.value.trim().length`**

Comment: can i add id attribute same as name like "<input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" value="${reqObj.address}" />"

Comment: Yes exactly correct..`<input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" value="${reqObj.address}" />`

Comment: Not Working
My Address field textbox is empty and when i click on Submit Button
Alert = "Address : [object HTMLInputElement]"
and call loginServlet.

var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress");
alert("Address : " + address);
if (address.trim().length == 0) {
 alert("Enter Address");
 return false;
}

<input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" value="${reqObj.address}" />

Comment: Previous issue has been resolved but
I have one dropdown list and i want to validate it also how can i do this

<select name="ddlIdp" id="ddlIdp">
  <option selected value="default">Select</option>
  <option>IDP 1</option>
  <option>IDP 2</option>
</select>

<script>
 function validateForm() {
  var idp = document.getElementById("ddlIdp");
  if(idp.value.trim().length == 0) {
   alert("Select IDP");
   return false;
  }
 }
</script>

Comment: If that is solved you can accept the answer..and for another issue solution is to `var element = document.getElementById("elementId");
var value = element.options[element .selectedIndex].value;
var text = element.options[element .selectedIndex].text;` so value will be selected value and text will be display text of option

Answer (score 1):

Define id of the input tag, since you are using `document.getElementById()` and the id cannot be found hence it is returning null every time.

Comment: Not the one downvoting you but I guess the one who did was because you should explain the problem and not provide just a correction ;)

Comment: Better :) you can put code with it (just an input example with an ID in this case), but only code isn't helpful.
(I gave you a +1 to help, I doubt the other one will pass again to remove his downvote)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have id for the address input , you can use [document.getElementsByName(name)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) instead.

```
var address = document.getElementsByName("txtAddress")[0];
```

or add ID to address element

```
<input type="text" id="txtAddress" value="${reqObj.address}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 validations instead. Here is jfiddle for the same
https://jsfiddle.net/ianoxley/VY8KU/

```
<input type="text" name="txtAddress" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're specified "txtAddress" as name but not id. Try accessing the element by creating id to it as follows

```
<input type="text" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" value="${reqObj.address}" />
```

If you're not interested to add id and you want to access the txtAddress value by name, then change the line in javascript function to as follows

```
var address = document.TestForm1.txtAddress;
```

address here is still an object. When checking validation for any input type, specify object.value instead of checking directly object. For ex:

```
var address = document.TestForm1.txtAddress.value;
```